# Cant get image iOS Rich Push notifications with Xcode, Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, rich-notifications

I already posted a question following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882711/ios-rich-push-notifications-with-xcode-swift3-but-cant-not-get-image).

I tried the code in the answers but still cant get message.

i did customize answers code like this:

**Code:**

```
import UserNotifications
import SDWebImage

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        print("hogehogehogehoge")

        func failEarly() {
            contentHandler(request.content)
        }

        guard let content = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent) else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["attachment-url"] as? String else {
            return failEarly()
        }

        SDWebImageDownloader.shared().downloadImage(with: URL(string: attachmentURL)!,
                                                    options: SDWebImageDownloaderOptions.continueInBackground,
                                                    progress: nil) { (image, data, error, flag) in

            guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(imageFileIdentifier: "image.gif",
                                                                    data: data! as NSData,
                                                                    options: nil) else { return failEarly() }
            content.attachments = [attachment]
            contentHandler(content.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)

            if let bestAttemptContent = self.bestAttemptContent {
                bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    static func create(imageFileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL?.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)

            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

**but cant output "hogehogehogehoge"** i dont know why process is not coming...

i'm showing my php fcm push message send with curl command

**php fcm push message send with curl command Code:**

```
public function push() {

        $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $AuthorizationKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        $subject = "ttt";
        $body = "bodyddd";

        $iOSArray = array(

                //topic name    
                'to' => '/topics/testtest', 
                'priority' => 'high', 

                //fcm payload               
                    'notification' => array(
                    'title' => $subject, 
                    'body' => $body, 
                    'alert' => "sssss", 
                    'mutable_content' => '1', 
                    'sound'=> 'default',
                    'badge' => '1',
                    'category' => 'myCategory',
                ),

                'data' => array(
                    'attachment-url' => "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/qiita-image-store/0/71694/5e08632a6a84409c6ed692141608d10b47f22766/medium.png?1468746973", 
                ),

            );

        // json
        $json = json_encode($iOSArray);

        //curl create
        $curlCommand =  "curl --header 'Authorization: key=" . $AuthorizationKey . "'" . " --header Content-Type:'application/json; charset=UTF-8'" . ' ' . $fcmUrl . ' ' .  " -d '".$json."'";

        // a new line delete
        $curlCommand = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $curlCommand);
        // exec curl
        print exec($curlCommand);
    }
```

and this is my AppDelegate swift as well

**AppDelegate swift Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { (grand, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                if grand {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            })
        } else {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound],
                                                      categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }


        return true
    }



    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        switch application.applicationState {
        case .inactive:

            break
        case .active:

            break

        case .background:
            ()

        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")



        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
         Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken



        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/testtest")

    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}


// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {


    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]

}
```

Sorry for writing such a long message.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Rich Push notifications with Xcode, Swift3 but cant not get image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882711/ios-rich-push-notifications-with-xcode-swift3-but-cant-not-get-image)

Comment: sorry this is my first time post so my bad...

Comment: It's may be problems of "mutable-content": 1

Comment: thank you very much for replying my message @VDPurohit any ideas how change from "mutable-content":1 to ? thank you very much.

Comment: this issue solved check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882711/ios-rich-push-notifications-with-xcode-swift3-but-cant-not-get-image) please thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file:-
set like bellow

```
data' => array(
    'attachment-url' => "https://s3-ap-northeast-  1.amazonaws.com/qiita-image-store/0/71694/5e08632a6a84409c6ed692141608d10b47f22766/medium.png?1468746973" , download = "true"

    //also set 
    "mutable-content": true or "mutable-content": 1

)
```

Hope it will help you.

Thank you

Comment: thank you sososo much for replying @V D Purohit. i tried this but dosent work... hmmm difficult...

Comment: thank you very much @V D Purohit. this issue solved check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882711/ios-rich-push-notifications-with-xcode-swift3-but-cant-not-get-image) please thank you very much again.